# Save a sf object in r as a shapefile with embedded style

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I use R to manipulate my data then take the vector files I generate into a GIS platform such as QGIS (because my datasets are large and cannot be easily interrogated using `leaflet`, `mapview`, etc.

I would like to save my point vector file as a shapefile with the styles embedded (e.g. colour) so I can open it in QGIS with the styles already created. Is there an easy way to do this from R?

Below is an example of how I would start to go about this. First I convert my tabular data to an sf object and define a named vector to be be used as a colour palette that I would like to use to colour samples using the column `Pred_Class`. I think have a line to export as a shapefile but unsure how I would embed the colour palette in the shapefile. I know that styles can be embedded in shapefiles in commercial GIS packages but unsure how to go about it in R.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

test_sf_object <- export_df %>%
      select(all_of(samp_id), all_of(x_loc), all_of(y_loc), Pred_Class) %>%
      st_as_sf(., coords = c(x = x_loc, y = y_loc), crs = 4283)

col_pal <- c(Class_1 = 'blue', Class_2 = 'green')

st_write(test_sf_object , 'test_sf.shp')
```

Comment: Do you have an example shapefile with embedded style you could use as a basis for exploration?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/control-the-colors-of-a-shapefile

Comment: I ma not sure "how big" your data are, but I would try 2 things:
1. set `mapviewOptions(platform = "leafgl")` and see if that enables viewing your big data in mapview
2. Add a column containing the color to your data and then `st_write()` your data. Potentially as a geopackage or flatgeobuf, which is generally preferable over shapefile.